# Get service tool error when trying to install vmware tools

Tags: vmware, ansible, vmware-tools

I am trying to install vmware tools on an EXSi host. This is the code I have to do it.

```
---
- hosts: my-host


  tasks:

      - name: Install VMware tools 
        yum: pkg="open-vm-tools" state=present
        when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

      - name: Enabling and starting -> vmtoolsd 
        service: name=vmtoolsd enabled=yes state=started
```

This is the error I get after I run the code.

> PLAY [my-host]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [setup]
>   ******************************************************************* ok: [myhost.com]
>
> TASK [Install VMware tools]
>   **************************************************** skipping: [myhost.com]
>
> TASK [Enabling and starting -> vmtoolsd]
>   *************************************** fatal: [myhost.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "failed": true, "msg": "get_service_tools not implemented on target
>   platform"}
>
> NO MORE HOSTS LEFT
>   *************************************************************  [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'vmwaretools.retry'.
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************* myhost.com : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1

This is the host file i am using.

> [my-host] 
>   myhost.com  ansible_ssh_pass=mypw
>   ansible_ssh_user=root

How can I implement get_service_tools on my host like the error message points out? I am fairly new to all of this so please pardon the naiveté. Thanks

Comment: As in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398399/installing-vmware-tools-on-virtual-machines-using-ansible), you need to execute tasks on your guest hosts, not on your host esxi.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Could you type that as an answer so i mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> As in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398399/installing-vmware-tools-on-virtual-machines-using-ansible), you need to execute tasks on your guest hosts, not on your host esxi.